# Finding short linear combinations in abelian groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algorithms, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

Let $M$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Assume we are given a presentation of $M$, that is
\begin{equation*}
M = \frac{\bigoplus_{i=1}^r \mathbf{Z}g_i}{\sum_{j=1}^s \mathbf{Z} r_j}
\end{equation*}
where the $g_i$ are the generators and the $r_j$ are the relations.

Let $x$ be an element of $M$, given as a linear combination of the generators. I want to express $x$ as a linear combination of the generators of the shortest length (EDIT : the length of a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i g_i$ is the number of nonzero $\lambda_i$'s). Is there an efficient algorithm to do this?

If that helps, I know that $M$ is torsion free and that $x$ generates the kernel of a family of linear operators on $M$ (given explicitly in terms of the generators).

My motivation for asking comes from the theory of modular symbols. If $M$ denotes the space of modular symbols of weight 2 on $\Gamma_0(N)$ and $x_E^\pm$ is the modular symbol associated to an elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{Q}$ of conductor $N$, I want to express $x_E^\pm$ as a short linear combination of the Manin symbols $\{g_i 0, g_i \infty\}$ with $g_i \in \Gamma_0(N) \backslash \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: It would be nice if you could state what you already know, for instance when $M = \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $g_1 = 2$ and $g_2 = 3$ and the like.

Comment: You could try to compute an elementary divisors basis of the numerator such that a relation is just a multiple of an element from that basis.

Comment: @Luc Guyot In the special case $r=2$ and $\mathrm{rk}(M)=1$ the module of relations is generated by a single vector $ag_1+bg_2$ with $(a,b)=1$ since $M$ is torsion free. Then a generator $x$ of $M$ cannot be a multiple of some $g_i $ unless $a$ or $b $ is $\pm 1$. I don't know if such an analysis extends for $r>2$.

Comment: @tj_ I haven't thought about this approach but in some sense I need to keep track of the original generators. In the special case where the module of relations is $\langle g_1,\ldots,g_{r'} \rangle$ I agree that the answer is trivial. In my case however each relation involve 2 or 3 generators -- they are of the form $g_i+g_j $ or $g_i+g_j+g_k $.

Comment: Burago proved that given a word metric in $\mathbf{Z}^d$, there exists a norm on $\mathbf{R}^d$ with rational polyhedral unit ball, such that the word length is equal to the restriction to the norm plus a bounded error. [D. Yu. Burago, Periodic metrics, in Representation Theory and Dynamical Systems, 205-210, Adv. Soviet Math. 9 Amer. Math. Soc. (1992).] I don't know how quantitative the proof is, but this should help getting an idea.

Comment: PS if I remember correctly, the polyhedron in my previous comment is the obvious one: the convex hull of the (symmetrized) generating subset. In particular, an optimal writing for a word should use a bounded number of letters outside extremal points of this polyhedron (for instance in $\mathbf{Z}$ with 1,2, we use 1 at most once; in $\mathbf{Z}$ with 2,3, we use 2 at most twice...).

Comment: Putting the matrix of relations into its Smith normal form and using the by-product transformation matrices yields an $k \times r$ matrice $A$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ of rank $k = \text{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ whose columns correspond to the generators $g_i$. Finding the shortest length of a word on $g_1,\dots, g_r$ is equivalent to find the minimum of the $\ell_1$ norm on the solution set of $Ax = b$ for some input $b \in \mathbb{Z}^r$. In the case $M = \mathbb{Z}$, we just look at the diophantine equation $\sum_i a_i x_i = b$.

Comment: I expect that when $M$ is given, there is a very efficient algorithm (and even something akin to a formula, depending on the class modulo some fixed number). But I don't claim this should be very efficient if $M$ is part of the input.

Comment: @all Thank you very much for your ideas, I will study them. Regarding the definition of the length of a linear combination, I simply take the cardinality of the support (ok, this is not a particularly natural metric, but it is adapted to my computations). My guess was that (in my case) it is not too hard to obtain a length roughly equal to the rank of $M$, but I hope to do better (on my examples the length is $\approx 3/5$ the rank on average). I don't know a good algorithm except the brute force one, which has tremendous complexity.